# Create this SVG with Raphael

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm working with inline SVG elements and I would like to run this in IE8, could anyone implement this with Raphael?

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="643px" height="735px" viewBox="0 0 643 735" enable-background="new 0 0 643 735" xml:space="preserve">
  <a xlink:href="img/interactive/pietraCT/00.jpg" rel="floors" title="zobacz rzut parteru">
    <g id="ct_00">
      <polygon  points="172.25,647 381.75,640.75 422,641.75 422,665 415.75,679.5 402.75,679.5 401.25,667 393.751,665 363.625,665 352.005,671.673 346,673 338.625,677 172.25,672.5"/>
    </g>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering SVG polygons in Raphael Javascript library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690241/rendering-svg-polygons-in-raphael-javascript-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690241/rendering-svg-polygons-in-raphael-javascript-library)

In short, you need to use the path() call, and you need to modify your points to adhere to the convention that Raphael uses (which is defined [here](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path))

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/A3ET9/) is a fiddle using your polygon. You'll have to scroll down in the bottom right window to see it though.

Comment: paper = new Raphael(0,0,1000,1000); i have one question what the 0,0,1000,1000 mean ?

Comment: its the size of the canvas. (x,y,width,height)