# Changing the style using box-shadow or any css tricks

Tags: html, css

If I have this:

[image: Before]

And I want this:

[image: After]

I want to change the right border to be like the second picture
What can I use to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/12710708/11854340